# Django:Is there a way to use a tree control in my template‏

Tags: python, django, treecontrol

Hi i wanted to know is there a way through which i could use a tree control in my template
I wanted to add something like

```
Student
    |_Name
       |_Address
       |_Contact No
```

I think you guys get the picture...How can i add something like that in my template...Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) has [template tags for displaying tree structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072301/how-can-create-a-json-tree-from-django-mptt). I'm not sure whether it would be difficult to use them without storing your data as a tree in the database. This could be used to generate markup or json data for some JavaScript tree widgets.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Django. You can use any HTML/CSS/Javascript in your templates, so just use any script to create your tree control.

Here is one of jQuery scripts: http://www.boarsoft.com/javascript/dtree/?jdfwkey=97rdf1

Other examples: http://www.google.lv/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+tree